# PHP Suggest Jobs within Location set by user field

Tags: php

Got a strange problem here on my little project, I have an account area that people can set a location so we can suggest job openings within the area they live in.

EDIT: Code indented - Sorry

The locations that do not work are "Maidstone" & "Medway". These locations are all stored in the database, When another user adds a job they can set the location the job is in and that will then add that job to the database under "State" String.

Other Locations such as Canterbury do work and the jobs that are listed under the Canterbury location show up on the users account as they should.

This php works for every location other then 2 of them which is really strange.

```
<?php

class SJB_Classifieds_SuggestedJobs extends SJB_Function
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $tp = SJB_System::getTemplateProcessor();
        $count_listing = SJB_Request::getVar('count_listing', 10, null, 'int');
        $current_user = SJB_UserManager::getCurrentUser();

                $properties = $current_user->getProperties();
                foreach ($properties as $property) {
                    if ($property->getType() == 'location') {
                        $fields = $property->type->child;
                        $childProperties = $fields->getProperties();
                        foreach ($childProperties as $childProperty) {
                            if (in_array($childProperty->getID(), array('State'))) {
                                $value = $childProperty->getValue();
                                switch ($childProperty->getType()) {
                                    case 'list':
                                        if ($childProperty->getID() == 'State') {
                                            $displayAS = $childProperty->display_as;
                                            $displayAS = $displayAS?$displayAS:'State';
                                            $listValues = SJB_StatesManager::getStatesNamesByCountry(false, true, $displayAS);
                                        }
                                        else
                                            $listValues = $childProperty->type->list_values;
                                        foreach ($listValues as $values) {
                                            if ($value == $values['id'])
                                                $phrase[strtolower($childProperty->getID())] = $values['caption'];
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        $phrase[strtolower($childProperty->getID())] = $value;
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                $phrase = array_diff($phrase, array(''));
                $phrase = implode(" ", $phrase);

                $listing_type_id = "Job";

                $request['action'] = 'search';
                $request['listing_type']['equal'] = $listing_type_id;
                $request['default_listings_per_page'] = $count_listing;
                $request['default_sorting_field'] = "activation_date";
                $request['default_sorting_order'] = "DESC";
                $request['keywords']['relevance'] = $phrase;
                $searchResultsTP = new SJB_SearchResultsTP($request, $listing_type_id, array('field'=>'keywords', 'value'=>$phrase));
                $tp = $searchResultsTP->getChargedTemplateProcessor();
            $tp->display('suggested_jobs.tpl');
        }
    }
```

Not sure if my problem is due to the PHP that tells which jobs to display.

Could someone just skip though the PHP and let me know if anythings wrong? I really want to work this out on my own however I'm alittle lost and if i can find out that the PHP is fine then I can figure it out some where else :)

Thanks!

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Also, what are those locations? Where do they come from? A database, perhaps? Are they strings, arrays...? And also, what do you mean when you say that it doesn't work?

Comment: Updated - Hope I've answered your question, I'm working off software that my brother owns just so I can learn the code and play with it.

I'll access the database and see if i see any irregularities with just those locations